# What would this error mean : error: Creating transport failed: noSupportedTransportAvailable

Tags: swift, signalr

So I am working on a SignalR iOS client application and when connecting via localhost the connection is successful but when trying with a server  I get this exception: 
***2019-12-12T12:52:10.046Z error: Creating transport failed: noSupportedTransportAvailable***

Here is my code:

```
var horses : [Horse] = []
let connection : SwiftSignalRClient.HubConnection


public init(url: URL) {
    connection = HubConnectionBuilder(url: url).withLogging(minLogLevel: .error).build()

     connection.on(method: "BroadcastMessage", callback: { (data: Message<Horse>) in
        print(data)

     })
     connection.start()
    print(url)
}

private func handleMessage(_ data : Message<Horse>) {
    // Do something with the message.

    print("Successful printing \(data.model)")
    self.horses.append(data.model)

    //test fetching of name 
    for h in self.horses {
        print("Hello, \(h.name)!")
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you enabled websockets in the server?

Comment: Yes , they are enabled.

Comment: did you solve this issue? if yes can you please post it here, since im getting the same issue